# Bulk deletion of records from Riak KV

Tags: riak

I tried to delete records id's wise like in Riak.

Example: I try with command line to delete single record :

```
curl -v -X GET http://localhost:8098/buckets/**bucket_name**/keys/**key_value**
```

and now I want to delete multiple records.

But I need bulk deletion of records and I am not able to delete with some range.

Can anybody tell me how we delete data in bulk?

Answer (score 0):

Riak KV doesn't have a bulk delete feature. In standard operations you need to iterate over the keys to delete.

Both the Bitcask and LevelDB back ends have expiration capabilities.

Bitcask: http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.2.0/configuring/backend/#bitcask
LevelDB: http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.2.0/configuring/global-object-expiration/